# Changing values of a lot of variables

Tags: spss

I want to change the missing values of a lot of variables into 0.I've written this code(There are a lot more of variables,it's just an example):

```
RECODE variable1 ($SYSMIS = 0).
EXECUTE.

RECODE variable2 ($SYSMIS = 0).
EXECUTE.

RECODE variable3 ($SYSMIS = 0).
EXECUTE.
```

Is there a simpler way to do the same?Like a while in programming or something like that

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step should be to combine all your commands into one - this can be done whatever the order of the variables - just explicitly mention all the variable names in the command (as david mentioned):

```
RECODE variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4 .... (sysmis=0).
```

This will save quite a lot of code already.
now, as Jignesh mentioned - for variables that are in consecutive order, you can use `to`:

```
RECODE variable1 to variable3 (sysmis=0).
```

or also an example with two groups of consecutive variables and two additional separate variables:

```
RECODE variable1 TO variable23 var1 TO var7 AnotheVar3 AnotheVar12 (sysmis=0).
```

definitely no need for looping commands here.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's great!

Answer (score 1):

If the desired target variables are in consecutive order in your active dataset you can use the [keyword TO](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_variables_to.htm).

For example:

```
RECODE V1 to V3 (SYSMIS=0).
```

Note your incorrect use of keyword "`SYSMIS`" in the `RECODE` command and the corrected in example code provided.

Else you will have to resort to using [DO REPEAT](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_do_repeat_overview.htm?lang=en) or [DEFINE/ENDDEFINE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_define.htm?lang=en).

Comment: Thanks mate. How about if they are not in consecutive order?I'm not sure if they are in consecutive order,I have to check it. And about the name of the missing value I've seen that: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476702  What do you think?

Comment: If the variables are not consecutive but there is some pattern in the names of the ones you want to modify such as the names all start with x or end with a common suffix or have other distinguishing metadata, you can use the SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES extension command to create a macro that lists them all.  It can then be used in the RECODE syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jignesh's response, If all of the variables are Numeric you can use ALL.

```
RECODE ALL(SYSMIS=0).
```

DEFINE !ENDDEFINE would be Overkill, DO REPEAT doesn't buy you anything over explicitly listing the variables in the RECODE command.

Comment: Thanks mate. I don't want to recode all of the variables and I guess your code do it. Am I wrong?